# Converting RockShox Pike DJ 2018 forks from 140mm to 100mm of travel

Tags: suspension, upgrades, conversion

I have a pair of RockShox Pike DJ forks at 140mm of travel that I bought fairly recently. The specific model number and details are as follows:

**Model ID:** FS-PIKE-DJ-A3

**Year:** 2018

**Spring:** Solo air

**Wheel size:** 26 inch

When I bought these it stated they could be converted to 100mm of travel which I am looking to do for dirt jumping. I cannot for the life of me work out what I need to buy to do this conversion. I have seen various RockShox Pike DebonAir Upgrade Kits online but I don't think any convert to 100mm of travel for these forks.

Comment: https://www.ambmag.com.au/feature/how-to-adjust-travel-on-a-rockshox-pike-441560  Also Perhaps https://www.servicearchive.sram.com/sites/default/files/techdocs/gen.0000000005294_2018_pike_revelation_service_manual_english_rev_c.pdf